# Redundant Message for Each row in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Whats wrong with my code?

```
   If DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Nothing to save.")
        Else
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

                If row.Cells(5).Value.ToString() = "" Then
                    row.Cells(0).Value = True

                    MsgBox("Please indicate your adjustment reason")
                Else
                    final_save()
                End If
            Next

        End If
```

I`m stopping the user to save data of some or all cells in 5th column of datagridview. The code above is working but the message repeats for every row empty that it finds

TYSM for future help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not exiting the loop. Try using `Exit For`. You should also only save if all rows pass the test.

```
       dim failed = false
       For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

            If row.Cells(5).Value.ToString() = "" Then
                row.Cells(0).Value = True

                MsgBox("Please indicate your adjustment reason")
                failed = true
                Exit for

            End If
        Next
        if not failed then final_save()
```

Comment: TYSM for the help